# Python prints a 0 elements matrix of my camera capture

Tags: python

I tried to print in the console the real time matrix of a camera capture, all that it shows me is a 0 element matrix, but when i read a random image and try to print the matrix of the image it works:

```
import cv2 , time

#THIS IS THE IMAGE AI READ
image = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\LionKing.jpg")
print("Your image matrix is :",image)

#This is the capture
video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
check, frame = video.read()
print(check)
print("Your capture matrix is :",frame)
video.release()
```

Result of a `print(frame)`:

[image: This is the random image matrix]

Comment: try some error checking, like ```video.isOpened()```

Comment: the video it s opend because i use imshow() functin and it shows me the camera capture